# Error in build from Dockerfile for Ubuntu image with Mono installed

Tags: xamarin, mono, docker, ubuntu-14.04, boot2docker

I have the following docker file that I am attempting to use to build a Ubuntu image with mono.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER John Smith <John.Smith@gmail.com>

RUN sudo apt-get update

RUN sudo /bin/bash -l -c apt-get install wget

RUN sudo /bin/bash -l -c apt-get http://download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg

RUN sudo apt-key add xamarin.gpg

RUN sudo echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

RUN sudo apt-get update

RUN sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

When I run the following  `docker build` command...

```
docker build -t="test/mono" .
```

It fails building and gives the following errors message:

```
gpg:can't open 'xamaring.gpg': No such file or directory.
2015/05/27 16:11:01 The command [/bin/bash -c sudo apt-key add xamarin.gpg] returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Anything obviously wrong sticking out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to use wget instead of apt-get after you installed wget, so 'xamaring.gpg' has not been downloaded and that's why it can't be found.

You need this:

```
/bin/bash -l -c "wget http://download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

The is an example of this in docker's website:

[Dockerizing MongoDB](http://docs.docker.com/examples/mongodb/)